# Diagonalisability of $AA^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can one prove that for every matrix $A$, $AA^*$ [$^*$ denotes conjugate transpose] can be diagonalised by using a unitary transformation?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Spectral theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectral theorem states that every Hermitian matrix (and for that matter, every normal matrix) can be diagonalized using a unitary transformation.

It therefore suffices to show that $(AA^*)^* = AA^*$.

Comment: I dont know what spectral theorem is, is there any easy way to show this?

Comment: @TejasP You'll really need to prove the spectral theorem anyway. It's not that hard to prove, and it is easy to look up.

Comment: If you want to prove your statement, then you should look up the spectral theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $AA^*$ is Hermitian and therefore normal. Therefore, the spectral theorem says that it is diagonalizable.

Comment: I dont know what spectral theorem is, is there any easy way to show this?

Comment: @TejasP You can prove it (for Hermitian matrices) by induction (for Hermitian matrices) on the dimension of your space.